# How can I fix an object error? Number to number or number to object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
const minutedata = document.getElementById("time02").innerHTML;
console.log(newnumber(minutedata))

function newnumber(num){
return num <10 ? ('0'+ {num} ) : num;}
```

But I get:

> 0[object Object]

Comment: would you share more code?

Comment: please update your question ..better  also add html code .. clear about what you try to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to prefix 0 if number is less than 10, you can try slice function for it.

```
const minutedata = document.getElementById("time02").innerHTML;
console.log(('0' + minutedata ).slice(-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write like this the newnumber function

```
function newnumber(num){
 num = parseInt(num);
    return num <10 ? '0'+ num  : num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function startTimer(){
document.getElementById("time02").innerHTML = document.getElementById("newtime01").value;
const minutedata = document.getElementById("time02").innerHTML;}
console.log(newnumber(minutedata))

function newnumber(num){
return num <10 ? ('0'+ {num} ) : num;}
```

Just that. I had just started.